# Overriding system shortcut keys

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

A friend of mine has difficulties in using both hands in the keyboard. He always use his left hand only. He asked me to write a C# program to send key combinations to the system so that it override the default shortcut keys.

For example he wants to replace <kbd>LWin</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> so that when he presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> it'll show his desktop.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it doesn't answer the question specifically for C#, but using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would actually be easier for this.  Plus it allows for simpler customization since it can be just a script if it's installed on his machine.  Otherwise it can be compiled and taken to other machines.

So the line would be like the following:

```
^l::SendInput #d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function.

See [here](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) for instructions on using it with C#.

Comment: The C# link gives a 500 error. Posting a brief C# example here would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a custom hardware solution instead?  You may be able to find a keyboard and driver that are more suitable to his abilities.